# Error Adding Variables in SPSS

Tags: spss

I am using the Data > Merge Files > Add Variables in SPSS. The two .sav files both contain a variable called "Student_No" which is numeric with the same width in each file. I am using this as the key variable in which to match cases. I am not indicating that cases are not sorted. It makes no difference if I indicate that the active or non-active data set is keyed. In either case the new variables are not properly matched with the cases.

What are some of the potential problems that might be causing this mismatch?

Comment: Please elaborate how they are not properly matched. Also please paste your command to syntax and add it to your post - it might help us to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog box pastes STAR JOIN syntax in some cases and MATCH FILES in others.  There were some problems with STAR JOIN in older versions of Statistics, so you might need to use MATCH FILES instead.  See the Command Syntax Reference for that command on how to do this.